# Lebesgue Theorem generalization

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

in my script that I use for college we have the Lebesgue Theorem two times - one for segment sets and the other for rectangle sets.

Just in case, the Lebesgue Theorem says that a function from $[a, b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (from $[a, b]\times[c, d]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in the case with a rectangle) is integrable if and only if its set of discontinuities' Lebesgue measure is zero.

I'm interested to know if there is a generalisation of this theorem. I.e. does it work if you just put the domain as an n-dimensional rectangle?

Comment: Yes, I understand that the measure changes depending on which space we observe. So what I gather here is that it works but it's not that simple?

Comment: So let's start with a correct statement in one dimension of the result you want to ask about in higher dimensions:  A bounded function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is *Riemann integrable* if and only if its set of discontinuities has *Lebesgue measure* zero.